What would a template header look like for use in a vimscript file (found in `$HOME/.vimrc`, et. al.)
What would a template look like for the header portion of a vimscript file that is commonly found in a plugin, or files found under Vi/Vim configuration (i.e., $HOME/.vimrc directory?

After perusing many (but not all) vimscript files in various repositories, I've gathered them into the following vimscript snippet:
" 
" Title:        myextension configuration file
" Description:  Vim syntax file for myextension configuration file
"               to perform syntax highlighting
" Maintainer:   jqsmith <john.q.smith@mysite.example>
" Version:      1.0
" Initial Date: 2020-04-24
" Last Change:  2020-05-13
" Filenames:    myextension, *.ext
" Location:     https://site.example/myextension
" License:      GPL (see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.txt)
" Bug Report:   https://site.example/myextension/issues
" Repository:   https://site.example/myextension/git
" Remarks:

Of course, there is legacy (untagged 1st line as a title) and there is evolution (new things like repository-concept, issue-link, versioning, license).
Some older variants (listed here one-line at a time):
" Author:      John Doe (jqdoe AT gmail?subject=[vim])
" Website:     http://www.vim.org/account/profile.php?user_id=9999999
" Created:     2008-07-10.
" Revision:    66
" GetLatestVimScripts: 2289 0 loremipsum.vim

Changes are welcome!
